# Asterisk silence until agent answers

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip, telephony, freepbx

Interesting issue I have never run into before with Asterisk.

Using Asterisk 1.8.x (please don't tell me to upgrade, it's not possible at this time).

When someone dial direct into the system to any of the numbers, we Answer, then push them to a queue and either play MOH on Ring sound.

This has always worked fine and still does. Most people forward calls to our numbers from their business line/phone system.

For this one customer and only one customer, there is complete silence for the caller once their phone system initiates the forward to our number. Our Asterisk box answers the call, we have even tried playing sounds using Playback etc but nothing, complete silence until one of the agents answers from the queue.

Really bizarre. canreinvite=no is set so, there shouldn't be any issues with Asterisk getting optimized out.

Any ideas a really appreciated. I know it's on their end but, it would be great to find a way to make Asterisk, make the customer's phone system behave correctly LOL.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to take a wireshark trace at Asterisk box and check INVITE offer and 200OK response from asterisk. Then make sure that media RTP are sent to IP address in connection information line c= and port specified on m= media line. You also should check if rtp payload (codec) match the request and answer. Asterisk probably will respond with one codec from INVITE offer. When media are sent but caller does not hear anything before an agent answer the issue is probably on caller side. Hope helped a bit to tracę the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once, but the other way around. I was the client dialing into someone else's system using my asterisk system. I tried everything in my hand, including pestering my (E1) telephony provider to no avail.

To this day I still don't know the reason for this behaviour, but I've managed to get around by Answering the call originated from my system BEFORE dialing the PSTN, thou this is far from ideal.

Something like this:

```
Answer()
...
Dial(YADAYADAYADA)
```

I know this isn't exactly the answer to your problem, but I hope it helps in any way.

Answer (score -1):

Very likly you have issues with codecs. I.e customer use some codec you have no translation module, but agent's customer have